I’m encountering an issue with the NET-iOS.Naxam.FSCalendar library while migrating my project from .NET 8 to .NET 9

/usr/local/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.iOS.Sdk.net8.0_18.0/18.0.8314/targets/Xamarin.Shared.Sdk.targets(1648,3): error :
clang++ exited with code 1:
ld: building for 'iOS-simulator', but linking in dylib (/Users/admin/.nuget/packages/net-ios.naxam.fscalendar/2.8.3.1/lib/net7.0-ios16.1/Naxam.FSC
alendar.iOS.resources/FSCalendar.framework/FSCalendar) built for 'iOS'
clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Build failed with 1 error(s) and 6 warning(s) in 19.4s
I attempted to migrate to .NET 9, as it likely includes a fix for syncing the storyboard with Visual Studio code, an issue that persisted in the previous version.

I would recommend you raise a bug with them and see if they have a fix for you
